# Getting ERROR: Please install mysql2 package manually, even though installed

Tags: javascript, json, macos, sqlite

Here are my index.js and config.json files:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('../config/config.json')[env];

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: config.dialect,
  storage: config.storage,
  dialectModule: require('mysql2')
});

sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

config.json:

```
{
  "development": {
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": "./database.sqlite3",
    "migrations-path": "./migrations" 
  },
  "test": {
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": "./database_test.sqlite3",
    "migrations-path": "./migrations"
  },
  "production": {
    "dialect": "sqlite",
    "storage": "./database.sqlite3",
    "migrations-path": "./migrations"
  }
}
```

Error after running `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`:

> Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
> Using environment "development".
>
> ERROR: Please install mysql2 package manually

I have tried installing mysql2 globally and using this command:
`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env development`, but nothing worked

Comment: `dialect: 'mysql',` change this line and Run the migration command again. `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate --env development`